# Does field have subtraction and division

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Most definitions  (e.g. this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Field.html) of a field I have seen define two binary operations: addition and multiplication and then axioms on them.
However, recently I came to a doc which stated field has subtraction and division also.
I am confused since as I said most definitions only define two operations: + and *.
How come subtraction or division is also defined?
Where are their rules specified?

Comment: The axioms require an additive inverse for all elements and a multiplicative inverse for all non-zero elements.

Comment: How do you define **subtraction** and **division** operations on a field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to define division as $a / b := a* b^{-1}$ for $b\neq 0$ and substraction as $a - b := a + (-b)$.

Comment: I see. this may sound stupid but the field rules don't say anything about what the result of a*pow(b,-1) should be right? just it is a multiplication of two elements of the field and that's it. and multiplication we already defined at least in the sense that it is some operation with some axioms. is my reasoning correct?

Comment: $b^{-1}$ is actually the **inverse** of $b$, whose existence is stipulated by the field axioms, as long as $b \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, while $a * b$ is multiplication of $a$ and $b$, $a/b$ means multiplication of $a$ and the inverse of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(K,+,\cdot )$ is a field, then $(K,+)$ is also an abelian group, so that the inverse of $x$ is $-x$, so we have subtraction. Similarly, since $(K^{\ast},\cdot)$ is a group, the inverse of $x\neq 0$ is $1/x$, so we have also division.

Comment: so in that sense it means we have subtraction defined also in any additive group?

Comment: Yes I see we define subtraction in terms of addition basically. addition is already defined. and existense of inverse also. but the axioms never say what result of some operation e.g. + should be just that it should satisfy some axioms.

Comment: not sure on what you said not true.

Comment: Thank you for answer I think I cleared all confusion now-check my first comment on Azlifs answer, that should highlight I think that I got the point.

Comment: What do you mean? I can't upvote your answer due to my low rep if thats what you mean. but thanks for help

Comment: Yes, sure, I just think, you can ask Azlif himself about comments to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you can define subtraction and division in terms of the more common definitions of "field".  So, for most purposes, there is no reason to add them.  But why would someone add those extra operations?  Perhaps for certain things done in model theory, it makes a difference what are the primitive operations, and what are only defined operations.

I could also imagine some work on computational efficiency, where subtraction and (more importantly) division are built-in operations of our computing model, and thus count as only 1 operation when we count the number of operations required in a computation.

So, the question is: what doc was that with this alternate definition?

Comment: no that doc just vaguely said field had +,-,* and / operations. i think i cleared up all confusion thanks all for help. subtraction is basically defined in terms of addition and thats it. and for `a` we know `-a` is also in set. hence a+(-a) is fine.